# Aligning images in a grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I really struggle with image alignment. I am trying to create a repeatable row where there is a header, then in a new row, there is a description with an image in the upper right, with the description wrapped around the image.
If I do display: inline, the image sits with the header (not below it). If I do a grid and try to force it to a new row, then it creates the odd column look as displayed.

```css
.section {
  
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
 
}

.sub-container {
  display: grid;
  display: inline block;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.sub-header {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  display: inline;
 
}

.sub-description {
  display: inline;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;

}

.image-box {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  float: right;
}
.image {
  float: right;
 grid-row-start: 2;
  max-width: 160px;
  max-height: 100px;
 
}
```

```html
    <div class="section">
      <div class="sub-container">
        <div class="sub-header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="sub-description">
        simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop pu
        </div>
        <div class="image-box"><img src="https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Frame-Gold-Love-Photo-Frames-free.png" class="image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-container">
        <div class="sub-header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="sub-description">
          simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop pu
        </div>
         <div class="image-box"><img src="https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Frame-Gold-Love-Photo-Frames-free.png" class="image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When you say `the description wrapped around the image` I imagine you want to use a floating image, not a grid, check the float: right example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the img element ABOVE the element I wanted to keep it to the right of worked. I'm not sure why. Will research. Wanted to post the solution I arrived at.

```css
.section {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
 
}
.image {
  float: right;
 
  max-width: 160px;
  max-height: 100px;
 
}
```

```html
    <div class="section">
      <div class="sub-container">
        <div class="sub-header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="sub-description"><img src="https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Frame-Gold-Love-Photo-Frames-free.png" class="image">
          simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop pu
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using display inline-flex for sub-container class

Answer (score 0):

I can see where you use your text without the

tag, so maybe that causes the problem.
Maybe you can try adding the

to your text and test this:

```
   img {
        float: right; 
        margin: 5px;
    }
    p {
        text-align: justify;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
```